# Estimating a multinomial sum

Tags: co.combinatorics, nt.number-theory, pr.probability, st.statistics, na.numerical-analysis

I have the following sum
\begin{equation}
\sum_{r_1=q+1}^{\tau}\dots\sum_{r_\lambda=q+1}^{\tau}{\tau\choose r_1,\dots,r_\lambda,\tau-r_1-\dots -r_\lambda} (\Lambda-\lambda)^{\tau-r_1-\dots-r_\lambda}
\end{equation}
and would like to estimate its value. Any ideas or techniques to do this? By the way, it is not always the case that $\tau>>q$, so the entire range of possibilities is necessary.

Comment: is $\lambda$ fixed positive integer and $\Lambda>\lambda$ fixed real?

Comment: yes to both. In addition, $\Lambda$, $\lambda$, $q$ and $\tau$ are also integers. I realize that using incomplete beta functions, for the case of $\lambda=1$, one can obtain a closed form expression, and for $\lambda=2$ then the incomplete beta function helps re-write the first sum, but then ends up inside the second sum. However, this is as far as I have gotten.  

Comment: I've found one reference that is quite useful: Levin, Ann Stat 9, 1123 (1981) for the cumulative of multinomial distributions.

Comment: Also, try a search of the questions and answers here in MO: there are a number of them about sum of multinomial coefficients close to yours.

Comment: As written the multinomial can have negative arguments. Is this intended?

Comment: No. I should have specified that if $\tau-r_1-\dots-r_\lambda<0$, then the coefficient is zero

Comment: You can find more multinomial CDF bounds in Appendix of van der Vaart's "Weak Convergence and Empirical Processes"